# How can I stop my function from modifying my passed in value?

Tags: javascript, value-type, reference-type

I have a function

```
function x10(a,b)
```

I define `a` as an array `a = [1]`. And the function `x10` pushes `b` zeros to `a`

```
x10 = function(a,b) {
  output = a;
  for(i=0;i<b;i++)
    output.push(0);
    return output;
}
```

I do NOT want this function to modify the argument `a`. If I write

```
print(a)
y = x10(a,2)
print(a)
```

I want a to be the same. Instead I get `a = [1]` before and `a = [1,0,0]` after.  How do I prevent a from changing while allowing `y` to take the desired value.

Comment: What is the problem with this?

Comment: Related [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Answer (score 4):

The `array` `a` is passed as a reference. That's why in your case `a` gets modified.

In ES6, you can use the spread operator to copy a new value.

***Note**: This will do a shallow copy*

```js
x10 = function(a,b) {
  output = [...a];
  for(i=0;i<b;i++)
    output.push(0);
  return output;
}
```

The important change is:

```js
output = [...a];
```

This [article](https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/35-es6-way-to-clone-an-array) may shed some more on light on what's happening.

Comment: "In JS primitive values are passed by value, whilst objects and arrays are passed by reference" - I know what you mean, but that's a misleading thing to say. Function arguments in JavaScript are passed by value. When you pass an object, you actually pass the reference to the object by value. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/430958/8338

Comment: Very true, thanks for the link, I have modified my initial statement.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var a = [1];
var x10 = function(a,b) {
  output = a.slice(0);
  for(i=0;i<b;i++)
    output.push(0);
    return output;
}

console.log(x10(a, 3));
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this way.It will works

```js
let a= [1];
x10=function(a,b)
{
  output =[].concat(a); //add this line instead of output = a
  for(i=0;i<b;i++)
    output.push(0);
    return output;
}
x10(a,2)
console.log(a)
```